# list index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
Tsup=[]
Te=0
dt=1
t=range(0,3600*2,dt)
r=len(t)
for i in range(0,r):
   Tsup.append(20)
....
   Tsup.append( (((Pj[i]+Ps-Pc[i]-Pr[i])*(dt))/((m_al*c_al[i])+(m_a*c_a[i])))+Tsup[i] )

   if i==r: 
      Te=(((Pj[i]+Ps-Pc[i]-Pr[i])*(dt))/((m_al*c_al[i])+(m_a*c_a[i])))+Tsup[i]

variacao=[]
T_est=0
for i in range(0,l+1):
    variacao.append(abs(Te-Tsup[i]))
    if variacao[i] < 0.1 and variacao[i-1] > 0.1:
       T_est=Tsup[i]
```

Aparece o erro "list index out of range" na linha variacao.append(abs(Te-Tsup[i])).

Comment: Acho que o `Tsup.append(20)` é desnecessário, você tá sempre colocando um valor de `20` no `Tsup` a cada iteração do primeiro `for`. Você poderia usar o próprio `Tsup_i` que é `20`, quando você quiser utilizar essa valor. Já sobre o erro `out of range`.  Você tem que se certificar que `Tsup` contém ao menos `l+1` itens.

Comment: Você esta tentando acessar um index que não existe na lista. Por exemplo acessar o elemento 4 de uma lista com 3 elementos.

Comment: O Tsup.append(20) era para definir que o 1º elemento da lista Tsup era 20, sendo assim devia defini-lo for do ciclo for, certo?

Comment: Cadê a variável `l`? O erro não está no `append`, mas no `Tsup[i]`, como apontado pelo @Math. Em algum momento `i` está maior que o tamanho da lista, pois ele vai de zero a `l+1`, então presumo que sua lista `Tsup` tem tamanho menor que `l+1`.

Comment: Foi engano e já editei, a variável l era r.
Eu tentei comentar a ultima parte e fazer print após "Tsup.append( (((Pj[i]+Ps-Pc[i]-Pr[i])*(dt))/((m_al*c_al[i])+(m_a*c_a[i])))+Tsup[i] )" para ver se percebia quais os valores de Tsup e o erro "list index out of range" passa a aparecer numa linha de código que eu não tenho aí e que está mais acima, ou seja, o erro vem de trás..

Comment: ok, achamos o erro, sua lista `Tsup` tem `r` itens e você tenta acessar um além do último, com o `for` que vai até `r+1`, se mudar para `r` ao invés de `r+1` deve resolver esse problema de `out of range`,  só não sei se a lógica estará certa.

Comment: Sim faz sentido. Já alterei os dois para for i in range(0,r): , mas continua a dar o mesmo erro "list index out of range" na linha variacao.append(abs(Te-Tsup[i])).

Comment: `Tsup` é um vetor certo? se ele for menor que `len(r)`vai acontecer esse erro mesmo

Comment: É uma lista. Então como posso resolver isto?

Comment: humm eu estava olhando com calma se `Pj`, `Ps`, `Pc`ou `Pr` forem menor que `len(r)` vai acontecer o erro mencionando, qual é o tamanho destas listas pj,ps,pc e pr ?? não podem ser menor que `7200` que é o seu `r`

Comment: Dentro do 1º for antes de calcular Tsup, é calculado:
Pj.append(((A)**2) * b * (1 + a * (Tsup[i] - (20+K))))
Ps = a_S * S * D
Pc.append(math.pi*la_f[i]*(Tsup[i]- Ta)*Nu[i])
Pr.append(math.pi*D*e*bo*(((Tsup[i])**4)-(Ta**4))).
como só dependem de i, terão o tamanho de r, certo?

Comment: sim todos tem que ser maiores ou iguais que `r` todas as suas listas você tem várias `Pr, Pj, Pc, c_a e c_al` verifique o tamanho de todas elas tem que ser maior, eu rodei seu código aqui e criei estas listas randomicamente o seu código rodou sem erro de index, tem outros erros como a var `l`que  não existe.

Comment: mas fazendo simplesmente isto:
dt=1 t=range(0,3600*2,dt) r=len(t) Tsup=[] Pj=[] Tsup.append(Tsup_i) for i in range(0,r): Pj.append(((A)**2) * R20 * (1 + a * (Tsup[i] - (20+K)))) print Pj 
dá logo erro list index out of range na linha Pj.append(((A)**2) * R20 * (1 + a * (Tsup[i] - (20+K)))), sendo que A, R20, a e K estão definidos no inicio. Como é possível?

Comment: @SofiaRaimundo é óbvio que vai dar erro `Tsup` você iniciou com tamanho vazio ele não é do tamanho de `r`

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro você fez um for de `r` elementos para preencher a variável `TSup`. Depois, você fez um for de `r + 1` elementos para acessar `Tsup[i]`. É natural que dê o erro `list index out of range`. O problema está aí. Eu não vi sua lógica, mas você precisa de fazer um loop de `r + 1` elementos? Se não, a solução é só colocar `for i in range(0,r):` ao invés de `for i in range(0,r+1):`, como foi colocado.

**EDIT**:

Existe um erro de sintaxe no primeiro for. Você não colocou os dois pontos : no final dele.

Um cuidado que você tem que tomar é quanto a identação, ok? O segundo for está identado sem necessidade. O interpretador vai reclamar disso.

Comment: Sim faz sentido. Já alterei os dois para for i in range(0,r): , mas continua a dar o mesmo erro "list index out of range" na linha variacao.append(abs(Te-Tsup[i])).

Comment: Copie o seu código e executei no meu computador e deu um erro de sintaxe. Com isso, eu editei a minha resposta. Dê uma olhada.

Comment: Obrigada pelo reparo, mas foi só um erro a passar para aqui, no meu código estão os dois pontos.

Comment: Como já referi eu inicializei Tsup em 20, ou seja, fiz com que o 1º elemento da lista Tsup fosse 20. Ao fazer isto: Nu_c_n.append(A2[i]*((G[i]*Pra[i])**m2[i]), com A2, G, Pra e m2 inicializados na forma A2=[] e sem lhe atribuir um valor inicial como a Tsup, pode ser a origem do erro?

Comment: Eu não sei. O seu código funcionou no meu computador. Eu tive que comentar a linha onde era feita a referência à variável `Pj` (acredito que você a inicialize em algum lugar do código não mostrado). E tudo funciona. Verifique se você está usando o arquivo correto.

Comment: De facto não entendo o que se passa.. Estou a tentar fazer por partes, para ver se encontro o erro com mais facilidade e simplesmente fiz isto agora:
dt=1
t=range(0,3600*2,dt)
r=len(t)
Tsup=[]
Pj=[]
Tsup.append(Tsup_i)
for i in range(0,r):
        Pj.append(((A)**2) * R20 * (1 + a * (Tsup[i] - (20+K))))

print Pj

e dá logo erro list index out of range na linha Pj.append(((A)**2) * R20 * (1 + a * (Tsup[i] - (20+K)))), sendo que A, R20, a e K estão definidos no inicio.

Comment: Você poderia postar o código completo? Eu gostaria de testá-lo no meu computador, mas existem algumas variáveis que não estão definidas no trecho de código que você postou.

Comment: Se você for postar o código por completo, eu gosto de usar este site http://pastebin.com/

Comment: coloquei nesse site agora mesmo o codigo completo.

Comment: Me passa a URL para que eu possa vê-lo, então?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/BNBM8tDM

Comment: O código que você me passou está diferente do código da questão que você criou. No código que você me passou, a variável `Tsup` só tem 1 elemento (ele executa somente um `append()`), porém você percorre `r` elementos.